# I used Boot Camp Assistant and can't boot OS X

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup

I installed Windows 10 on my Mac using Boot Camp Assistant. When I got into Windows, it asked me if I wanted to install Boot Camp. I selected yes. Now, when I try to restart in OS X, it says "can't locate OS X boot volume"

Additionally, when I hold down the option-key while restarting, I get a windows option, and then a second option that tries to install windows.

Here is a picture of my Disk Management screen and the also the error when I try to restart in OS X.

[image]

[image]

I feel like the OS X volume still exists, but windows isn't recognizing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Windows can't read APFS.

To get back to macOS you need to hold the  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  key at startup.

BTW, don't ever let Windows adjust anything on your drive. Consider that Disk Management tool as a read-only utility. It doesn't understand how it's being fooled into thinking it's in charge & will break things.

Comment: Right, so I've held down the Option-Key during startup and all I see are two Windows drives. One takes me to my current windows operating system, the other tries to install Windows all over again. Additionally, all this was done without me doing any tinkering. I finished installing from Boot Camp Assistant, tried to go back, and this was the error I got

Comment: Hmm..ok. Looks like BCA didn't remove the OSXReserved partition when it was finished. Can't tell what has happened to the rest. At this point I'd be tempted to either get the drive out, or boot to Target Disk mode using another Mac  & see what you can see from there, because this can't be fixed from inside Windows. I'd also get [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) to have a look at it. Or try Internet Recovery for a disk check &/or restore from Time Machine.